Database/Schema Comparison
Does anyone know articles regarding databases and schema comparison state-of-the-art?
I am searching but haven't been able to find anything but the tools' features (e.g. Schema Compare from SSDT). I need some articles regarding the state-of-the-art of these tools.
Thank you in advance
